# Razor IntelliSense doesn't work very well

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've always noticed for as long as I can remember that IntelliSense only works some of the time in Razor views.

For example, it won't suggest `Html` or `Model` even though they should be in scope and compile okay.

[image]

No one else seems to complain. Am I doing something wrong?

(I work alone, so I can't exactly turn to my colleagues, I asked my wife but she gave me a funny look).

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2012. Get Update 4 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305

Comment: I'm running Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 and its still bad.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but I too have encountered this issue quite a bit (mostly with VS2010, not so much since I upgraded to 2013). Sorry I can't be of any help, but you're definitely not alone experiencing this, I know how annoying it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, an utterly non-technical, last-resort, no-more-doubting-myself restart of the IDE did the trick.

Until next time.

If this question attracts votes I'll see if I can find some votes left for a UserVoice ticket.

Comment: when in doubt, restart the IDE, Log out of the OS and back in, and/or restart the computer.  Either one or a combination of those will usually get things working again.